# Can I leave voice messages via Echolink using my 2-meter handheld?

Tags: 2m-band, echolink

I am (KB3IFP) going on a 400 mile bike ride in the middle of West Virgina with 0 access to cell reception. I have a 2 meter handheld and a small book of all the US repeaters. I like to 'check-in' every evening/morning so my family knows I am OK. I could buy a Delorme GPS with texting capabilities via sat but what's the fun in that? My brother is K3OD and he has a HF station back in Pittsburgh. Is there a way to have my brother use Echolink to monitor a freq/channel using Echolink and record any messages I transmit? Am I thinking of this all wrong? What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can leave voice messages with your radio, **if** the EchoLink server you connect to (via RF) has the [svxlink](http://www.svxlink.org/) server daemon running on a Linux system. This can be done with any DTMF capable radio.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used EchoLink myself, but from listening while other people are using it on the local repeater, and reading the web site, it seems that EchoLink does *not* have any kind of store-and-forward messaging capability, only real-time communication.

You could use it to talk directly with your brother if he is available at the same time, but you would be limited to repeaters which have functioning EchoLink nodes.

---

I'm not aware of anything commonly available that will let you pass on *voice* messages, but I have two suggestions for alternatives:

- **Ask people to relay your messages home.** (You could do formal radiograms, even.) This sort of thing is not done often in these days of the Internet and cell phones, but some people will very much enjoy helping your message along.
- **Use APRS.** You can transmit APRS messages which contain your current location and whatever text you want; wherever there is APRS digipeater/IGate coverage, your messages will be passed to the Internet (e.g. on http://aprs.fi/).

  This does require some more hardware, but I hear it can be as simple as your HT, your smartphone, and an audio interface cable.

Comment: When I was posting this, I was thinking of APRS as a solution even though I do not know much about it. Will investigate it. Thanks!